# How can I remove preview button from contact form?

Tags: 8, emails

How to turn off preview in contact form in Drupal 8.1.x

### [image]

Comment: Use some css and remove it from the display.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A custom module can utilize [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.1.x) to strip out the preview button form element in any form:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

  // Look for any form provided by the contact module.
  // If you want to target a specific form you'll use the whole form ID
  // (e.g. Website feedback = 'contact_message_feedback_form').
  if (strpos($form_id, 'contact_message_') !== FALSE) {
    $form['actions']['preview']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Comment: If I remember well the preferred way to remove a form element instead of using unset() is by setting the #access property to FALSE, so:   $form['actions']['preview']['#access'] = FALSE;

Comment: It doesn't work for action buttons in D8. If this has been fixed or there's an alternative (I didn't have the time for research what's going on there), feel free to update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Seems to work fine. I updated the snippet

Comment: Did it via theming instead, `hook_form_form_id_alter()` hook, full code snippet (works for a default contact form): `function THEME_form_contact_message_feedback_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['actions']['preview']['#access'] = FALSE;
}`

Answer (score 1):

It's works for me The best way to do that Add this code your YOURPROFILENAME.profile file

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function YOURPROFILENAME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
   if (strpos($form_id, 'contact_message_') !== FALSE) {
    $form['actions']['preview']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are patches under work and testing but no commits yet https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2960353. Patches work on latest D8 to date, but until a patch has been committed, suggest to use Hide Preview Button module https://www.drupal.org/project/hide_preview works well for other form pages, too. In case, this helps those not comfortable with working with hooks and patches.

Answer (score 0):

I support the answer suggesting to remove the "Preview" button via the "Manage Form Display":

> You can go to Manage Form Display for the desired contact form and
> move the "Preview sender message" to "Disabled".

But, you need to **clear cache** before it takes effect.

For me, it is the simplest solution.

Answer (score -1):

Starting Drupal version 9.1, you can go to Manage Form Display for the desired contact form and move the "Preview sender message" to "Disabled". That hides the preview button in the form.