# Remove the Preview button on the Contact Form

Tags: emails

In in Drupal 8.5 (Theme Bartik), although I disabled in the UI the Preview button,  as shown in the picture below, it still shows up in the contact form page.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I remove the button? (I would like to avoid using CSS to do it)

[image]

Comment: function Your_module_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) { $form['actions']['preview']['#access'] = FALSE;}

Comment: Thanks Vikram, I''m pretty new in Drupal, here can I place this code? Sorry for the ignorance

Comment: place the code in your in your themes folder file "your_theme.theme" file  Yourthemename_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) { $form['actions']['preview']['#access'] = FALSE;}

Comment: I place the code and repalce it with "my_theme_name" but it doesn work. The code was: <?php

filhos_do_porto_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) { $form['actions']['preview']['#access'] = FALSE;} and the message errour was: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
ParseError: syntax error, unexpected '&' in Drupal\Core\Extension\Extension->load() (line 3 of themes/custom/filhos_do_porto/filhos_do_porto.theme). Can you tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: you dont need to use php tag in .theme file its already included in the file, write code without using <?php delimeters ?>

Comment: If I remove the <?php delimeter it just prints the code on top of my site's pages... I tried it before and doesn't work---

Comment: have your ever created custom module in drupal 8?

Comment: in your_module.module file write the codein custom module: use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface; function your_module_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) { $form['actions']['preview']['#access'] = FALSE;}

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/209078/how-can-i-remove-preview-button-from-contact-form/209090 ,also dont forgot to add "use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface; "at the top of the .module file

Comment: I never created a custom module, I will try to study how to do it. thanks for the tip. its a very hard solution for this issue